# Python parser error con evaluador de expresiones

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Hola veran llevo tiempo implementando varios metodos numericos en python, en este caso estoy implementando el de biseccion y funciona perfectamente pero el problema esta en el evaluador de expresiones que me esta dando un error que no entiendo, aqui va el codigo asi como esta funciona perfectamente evalua la funcion y me da la grafica, pero si intento evaluar la funcion `x^4 + 3x^3 - 2` me da el error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "F:\bisection3.py", line 19, in 
>      fa = f('x^4 + 3x^3 - 2', 'x', a)
>    File "F:\bisection3.py", line 11, in f
>      result = p.parse(exp).evaluate({var:x0})
>     File "C:\Users\DanielPortatil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\py_expression_eval__init__.py", line 610, in parse
>      self.error_parsing(self.pos, 'unexpected variable')
>     File "C:\Users\DanielPortatil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\py_expression_eval__init__.py", line 639, in error_parsing
>      raise Exception(self.errormsg)
>   Exception: parse error [column 8]: unexpected variable

y no entiendo porque unexpected variable... en el siguiente codigo funciona bien no da el error, pero si yo cambio la funcion a evaluar por `x^4 + 3x^3 - 2` me dara ese error. Si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradezco mucho, intente con la funcion `x^4 + 3 - 2` y funciona osea que el no esta siendo capaz de leer una segunda `x` es lo que me da entender.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from py_expression_eval import *


def f(exp, var, x0):
    p = Parser()    
    p.ops2['^'] = np.power    
    p.ops1['sin'] = np.sin    
    p.ops1['tan'] = np.tan   
    p.consts['e'] = np.e    
    result = p.parse(exp).evaluate({var:x0})    
    return result

a = 0   
b = 100   
error = 10   
i = 0

while(error>1e-8 and i!=100):   
    c = (a + b) / 2    
    fa = f('x^2 + tan(x^3) - 5', 'x', a)    
    fc = f('x^2 + tan(x^3) - 5', 'x', c)    
    if(fc == 0):    
        raiz = c    
        break

    elif(fa * fc < 0):    
        b = c    
    else:    
        a = c    
    raiz = c    
    i += 1    
    error = abs(fc)    
    print("Iteracion",i,". Raiz aproximada:",raiz)    
print(raiz)    
print(i)    
print(f('x^2 + tan(x^3) - 5', 'x',raiz))    

x = np.linspace(0, 15, 101)  
#plt.plot(x, f('x^3 -2 * x^2 - 1','x',x))    
plt.plot(x, f('x^2 + tan(x^3) - 5','x',x))    
#plt.plot(a, f('x^2 + tan(x^3) - 5','x',a), 'or')   
plt.grid()   
plt.show()
```

Acabo de intentar de la siguiente manera: 
`x^4 + 3*x^3 - 2`  y asi no da el error y la evalua, pero esa no es la idea de un evaluador de expresiones, deberia de funcionar sin necesidad de agregarle el `3*x^3`. Si alguien conoce como hacer para que reconosca `3x^3` como `3*x^3` se lo agradezco mucho

Comment: No usé nunca py_evaluate, pero por las dudas: la expresión `x^4 + 3x^3 - 2` no debiera ser `x^4 + 3*x^3 - 2`?

Comment: @Patricio Moracho si amigo por eso digo al final de la pregunta que colocando la funcion como dices con el * no me da error, pero es que quiero que el usuario no tenga que poner el * porque pues el evaluador deberia reconocer que un numero al lado de la variable es una multiplicacion verdad :p

Comment: Implementa tu propio evaluador ,crea tu gramatica formal analizador lexico y sintactico que hagan lo que quieres si crees que vale la pena el efuerzo, el de python esta implementado de esa forma y si ya se usa x^2   que  tiene de raro 3*x^2. El * se usa en java, java script c++ ... etc y hasta en la calculadora de window es casi universal en la computadora.